Numerical Calculus of Variations, is this reasoning correct?
I am having trouble finding specific material on using numerical analysis to solve variational problems on manifolds. So I am trying to derive the math based on my knowledge of it, I need to check if I am on the right ballpark.
Functions as a vector space
Let's restrict ourselves to the simple case of all continuous functions connecting two fixed points $p_1, p_2$ over $\mathbb{R}^2$. These functions will look like $C(t) = {X(t), Y(t)}$ where $X, Y$ are smooth real functions.
Fourier analysis tells us that $X = \sum_{i=0} a_i\phi_i; Y =  \sum_{i=0} b_i\gamma_i$ where $\phi_i, \gamma_i$ are standing for the fourier basis.
Discretizing the parametric function
We can then assume a discretization by picking a finite number of members of the fourier basis. Say we only want the $n$ first elements.
Then we can re-characterize $C$ as $C(a_1,\cdots,a_n, b_1, \cdots, b_n)$. I.e. since $X, Y$ are uniquely characterized by the coefficients of their fourier basis, then we can define $C$ as a vector function of the coefficients.
Optimizing
Now say I have a functional $F$ acting on the space of functions, this could be the baristochrone functional, or the arclength functional...
Then $F(C) = F(\sum a_i \phi_i, \sum b_i \gamma_i)$, but once more, we can just treat $F$ as a function of the coefficients, meaning it is a vector function $F(a_i, b_i)$.
So if one can evaluate $F$ given any valid set of $a_i, b_i$, then one can take the numerical gradient with respect to the vector $<a_i, v_i>$ and do gradient descent (or hessian descent or any other fancy numerical optimization method).
Result
So in my head, to do numerical analysis in this setting one would:

Write $C$ with respect to $a_i \phi_i, b_i \gamma_i$ applying differential operators where needed until we reach a closed form solution that can be used to evaluate a number given the coefficients.

From this point onwards, just use traditional optimization methods for vector valued functions.


Is this approach at all correct?

sounds like the Fourier-Galerkin truncation.

This is more or less what people do in practice. The only subtle point is the order in which you discretize and take the gradient of the functional. It tends to be more consistent and stable if you take the functional gradient then discretize that as opposed to discretizing the functional then computing the gradient.
